# How to set the path of uploaded photos in flask

Tags: python, flask, image-upload

I am trying to upload an image and run opencv with the received image.
It says that the file upload was successful, but I don't know how to set the path to use the uploaded image instead of the absolute path in the img part.
This is file upload.

```
@app.route('/', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def uploader_file():
   if request.method == 'POST':
      f = request.files['file']
      f.save(secure_filename(f.filename))
      return redirect(url_for('test'))
```

this is html

```
 <html>
      <head>
        <title>얼굴황금비율인식AI</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <h1>얼굴황금비율인식 AI</h1>
        <img src="{{ url_for('video_feed') }}">
        <h2>사진을 업로드 해주세요</h2>
        <form action = "" method= "POST"
          enctype = "multipart/form-data">
          <input type = "file" name = "file"/>
          <input type = "submit"/>
        </form>
      </body>
    </html>
```

I don't know how to set the image path to the received file.

```
 img = "C:\\Users\\20khj\\Desktop\\photo.jpg"
 img = cv2.imread("C:\\Users\\20khj\\Desktop\\photo.jpg")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this to save image:

```
@app.route('/', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def uploader_file():
   if request.method == 'POST':
      f = request.files['file']
      f.save("/static/"+f.filename) 
      # You may write that f.filename by yourself to save in any name as you want : 
      f.save("/static/"+"photo.jpg")
      return redirect(url_for('uploader_file'))
```

And to get that image:

```
@app.route("/video_feed")
def video_feed():
    return redirect("/static/photo.jpg")
```

Comment: After uploading the file, it was successfully saved in the static\image file. But here, how do I use the uploaded photo instead of the fixed path in the img variable to be used in opencv?

Comment: I didn't understand you clearly. You want to save file using `opencv`?